# Incrementing an int in a C code for microcontroller only moves the LSB

Tags: c, microcontroller, 8051

I am wondering if someone could help me with a strange problem I'm having with the Silicon Labs C8051F040.

The problem is that I am using an `unsigned int` variable as a counter, which means that naturally I need to do something like `variable++`.

Well, my problem is that when the variable is allocated in the embedded memory the increment is OK

But when it is allocated in the external memory (not really external, but not embedded in the core), the LSB is incremented OK but the MSB is always in FF until an overflow happens, which sets it to 00 and after a new increment, it turns to FF again until a new overflow of the LSB.

I made a `main()` with only `variable++` as instruction, and the same problem happens.

I tried to move the variable along the different parts of the external memory and the same happens. I read the ASM code generated by the compiler and the instructions look OK.

I really don't know what to do with this... I also "played" with the amounts of stack and heap memory without luck...

```
__xdata int variable;

void main()
{
  variable = 0;
  while (1)
  {
    variable++;
  }
}
```

What I can see with the debugger is that the variable starts with 0x0000 and after the first itaration the value reachs the 0xFF01, then 0xFF02, 0xFF03, etc. until 0xFFFF, when the next iterations set the value to 0x0000 and then start again with 0xFF01.

If instate of declaring the variable in the __xdata memory I use the __data memory, there is no problem. I can't copy the ASM code now 'cause I'm not in the lab, but I have to say that is correct, I'm sure about it.

I think that I'm having a memory problem related with the memory distribution, could be?

Thanks

Comment: It is better to provide some code, log files, etc. so that people can help better.

Comment: Can you share some further information about the issue? In particularly precisely where is the counter allocated, how does the C and generated assembly code look? Furthermore how do you know that the counter isn't wrapping, that is does it affect the semantics of the code, debugger view or something else?

Comment: Oh, and if there is an external memory bus involved then there are quite a few possible pitfalls. So please share what you can of the schematics and part numbers, wait-state/width/multiplexing and other interface settings in the MCU, the clock rate and so on.

Comment: The problem could be some unwanted masking, bus dataline problems, a protocol bug... the scenario is to broad to give an answer... :-)

Comment: Check the address pins are all connected.

Comment: Does the microcontroller have alignment requirements for multi-byte variables?  Does this particular variable conform to those alignment requirements?

Comment: What happens if you just *assign* a constant value to your `unsigned int` to your counter? Do you get the value MSB,LSB properly? Is this custom hardware, or an off-the-shelf development kit?

Comment: Hi Elyasin, you're right, I should include code.

Comment: Well, first of all, I have to clarify that there is no bus, is the memory of the uC.

Comment: The code I'm trying to check is this one:

Comment: As @lurker suggested, assigning a constant value, instead of incrementing will help in pin-pointing the issue

Comment: If you have a uC and memory, then you have a bus. That's the term used to describe the parallel data and address paths between a uC and memory hardware. You haven't said whether this is custom hardware or an off-the shelf development kit. You've really provided very little information that would enable someone to narrow down your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to duplicate your issue with Keil C51, and it should not be a surprise that I did not see your problem.

I suspect you are using the debugger incorrectly, perhaps looking at the wrong address or interpreting with the wrong type?

For you to compare, here is the ASM listing generated by the Keil compiler.

```
     6: void main() 
     7: { 
     8:   variable = 0; 
C:0x0800    E4       CLR      A
C:0x0801    900000   MOV      DPTR,#C_STARTUP(0x0000)
C:0x0804    F0       MOVX     @DPTR,A
C:0x0805    A3       INC      DPTR
C:0x0806    F0       MOVX     @DPTR,A
     9:   while (1) 
    10:   { 
    11:     variable++; 
C:0x0807    900001   MOV      DPTR,#0x0001
C:0x080A    E0       MOVX     A,@DPTR
C:0x080B    04       INC      A
C:0x080C    F0       MOVX     @DPTR,A
C:0x080D    70F8     JNZ      C:0807
C:0x080F    900000   MOV      DPTR,#C_STARTUP(0x0000)
C:0x0812    E0       MOVX     A,@DPTR
C:0x0813    04       INC      A
C:0x0814    F0       MOVX     @DPTR,A
    12:   }
```